# Next available product code depending on category without duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns,Column A and Column B.

Column A has all existing product codes.

Column B has all existing and new product categories.

Old Product codes consists of two parts
two letters and a 6-digit number
the letters always remain the same
ER
the numbers were picked at random.
So existing product codes are between ER000001 and ER999999

New product codes will follow a new pattern
"ER" + Product Category + a number
For example, if product category is 14
All the new product codes in this category should be
ER140001 up to ER149999

I need a formula that will create new product codes but not use any of the old ones

I have tries a million things and I am afraid I cant find a solution.

```
[A           B
ER044747    05
ER044748    05
ER044749    05
ER044750    05
ER044753    05
ER069317    18
ER069318    18
ER054304    18
ER054305    18
ER054445    18
ER031089    17
ER031106    17
ER031132    17
ER031134    17
ER031154    17
ER031161    17
ER031178    17
ER031179    17
            14
            14
            27
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

type ER into A1 cell, type '14' into B1, then put `=row()` in C1, and put `=A1&B1&text(C1,"000000")` in D1 cell. Drag all downwards.. observe the results in column D.

That shall get you to what you need. Have a check. ( :